Formatting of column labels for concatenated pd.DataFrames
the following is part of a method in a class in python. The first line calls another method and unpack the results into two lists. After that, I DataFrame each list and I put them together with a separator column in the middle. The Column names are "down", "unch.", "up".
I would like to put the names Marc and John over the names of the columns, but I can not figure out how centre them. What I get with this code is that "Marc" and "John" appear over column "up", not visually pleasing. Is there a way to centre them?
    marc_values, john_values = self.aggregator(geo)
    
    # Formatting results into a single DataFrame
    columns = ["Down", "Unch.", "Up"]
    index = ["A", "B", "C"]

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(marc_values, columns=columns)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(john_values, columns=columns)
    separator = pd.DataFrame([["", ""], ["", ""], ["", ""]], columns=["", ""])
    return pd.concat([df1, separator, df2], axis=1, keys=["Marc", " ", "John"])

